# Exporting As PDF opens only second chart

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Trying to export my "Report" worksheet as a PDF and open it. Issue is that all that's opening up is the second chart at the bottom of that worksheet.

My code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Report.pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

What's supposed to be showing in the PDF:

[image]

What's actually showing up in the PDF:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `Worksheets("Report")` instead of `Sheets("Report")`?

Comment: Yes, but no dice.

Comment: I've also tried forcing an area to be printed by using: Worksheets("Report").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$46" but that didn't work.

Comment: If I post my code, maybe there's something in it messing up which sheet is active? I doubt it but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a well known problem of Excel: For it `ActiveSheet` can be a Chart, too...
If you have an active chart, this one will be exported.

So, it is enough to place before the exporting line :

`ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select`

Or be sure that a chart is not selected and even better, try qualifying your sheet as:

`Dim sh As Worksheet`

`Set sh = Worksheets("sheet_name")`

Comment: @PaperCupStraw: Glad helping you! It happened to me some years before and I used to dig in order to understand what was going wrong...

Comment: I think I was in the same spot as you were years ago!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code before exporting:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
```

Comment: Did not work. I'm going to post my full code here and will link my post, maybe it's got something to do with something, I dunno.